# Combining Date and Time input strings as a Date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have two input tags for picking date and time from user.

```
<p>Start Date</p><p> <input ng-model="sdate" type="date" ></p>
<p>Start Time</p><p> <input ng-model="stime" type="time" ></p>
```

These two values are passed to a function where I want to combine these two input values as a `Date` object:

```
 new Date(y, m, d, hh, mm, a)
```

Which I can then use to plot an event's details in a Calendar. How can I combine these two values? I have tried:

```
start:new Date(sdate + stime)


start:new Date(sdate , stime)


start: new Date(sdate.getFullYear() + sdate.getMonth() + sdate.getDate() + stime.getHours + stime.getMinutes())
```

But none of what I have tried is working.

How do I achieve this when using AngularJS?

Comment: Doesn't Angular just create native HTML5 date inputs in supporting browsers, and what would the returned value from those be in different browsers ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In angular it would go something like this:

Controller:

```
function exampleController($scope) {
    $scope.title = "$Watch sample";   

    $scope.$watch('sdate', function() {
       tryCombineDateTime(); 
    });

    $scope.$watch('stime', function() {
       tryCombineDateTime();
    });

    function tryCombineDateTime() {
        if($scope.sdate && $scope.stime) {
            var dateParts = $scope.sdate.split('-');
            var timeParts = $scope.stime.split(':');

            if(dateParts && timeParts) {
                dateParts[1] -= 1;
                $scope.fullDate = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined,dateParts.concat(timeParts))).toISOString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="exampleController">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>Start Date</p><p> <input ng-model="sdate" type="date" ></p>
    <p>Start Time</p><p> <input ng-model="stime" type="time" ></p>

    {{fullDate}}
</div>
```

You need to make use of the $watch listener on a variable when it changes, then call your function.

Note: it would be even better if you make a directive for this.

[Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyr4M/1/)

Comment: Don't forget that the month is zero referenced when using `Date` and so you will need to subtract 1 or the month will be incorrect.

Comment: Not working, getting an error that split is not a function

Answer (score 3):

A very naive approach to combine these two is to split date-components and time-components and make a string. Then make a new Date object using this string.

Input is taken from here:

```
<p>Start Date</p><p> <input ng-model="sdate" type="date" ></p>
<p>Start Time</p><p> <input ng-model="stime" type="time" ></p>
```

Then in script part, split date and time components as follows:

```
        var dd = new Date(sdate).getDate();
        var mm = new Date(sdate).getMonth()+1;
        var yy = new Date(sdate).getFullYear();
        var hh = new Date(stime).getHours();
        var ms = new Date(stime).getMinutes();
```

Then Combine these components to form a string as required(in Calendar):

```
var x = yy + ',' + mm + ',' + dd + ' ' + hh + ':' + ms;
```

Now create a new Date object:

```
var finaldate = new Date(x);
```

Comment: This would assume that the environment's `Date` constructor parses the strings correctly, which is often not the case. Otherwise you could just shorten this to `new Date(sdate + ' ' + stime)` and forgo the multiple parsing that you are performing.

Comment: Actually, I tried your method initially, but it wasn't working. Also can you provide details about in which case parsing won't work correctly?

Comment: This is problem, parsing a datetime string in Javascript using `Date` is unreliable. Search here on SO and on Google and you will find links to tabulated results.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, though this doesn't have anything to do with [`AngularJS`](http://angularjs.org/) and I can't test on older browsers. I am assuming that you are entering date/time as [`UTC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and I am using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create an [`ISO8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamp as an output. Also assumes that you are using a modern browser that supports [`HTML5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and [`ECMA5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), otherwise you will need to modify the code.

HTML

```
<p>Start Date</p><p> <input id="myDate" ng-model="sdate" type="date" ></p>
<p>Start Time</p><p> <input id="myTime" ng-model="stime" type="time" ></p>
<div id="myIso"></div>
```

Javasceipt

```
var myIso = document.getElementById('myIso'),
    dateParts,
    timeParts;

function joinPartsAsDate() {
    if (dateParts && dateParts.length === 3 && timeParts && timeParts.length === 2) {
        // dateParts[1] -= 1; could be done here
        myIso.textContent = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, dateParts.concat(timeParts))).toISOString();
    } else {
        myIso.textContent = '';
    }
}

document.getElementById('myDate').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    dateParts = e.target.value.split('-');
    if (dateParts[1]) { // this could be done in joinPartsAsDate, here for clarity
        dateParts[1] -= 1;
    }

    joinPartsAsDate();
}, false);

document.getElementById('myTime').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    timeParts = e.target.value.split(':');
    joinPartsAsDate();
}, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KrRzu/)

Answer (score 1):

After testing all stuff described here, i found a very simple solution.
In my view i have

```
<input type="date" ng-model="tsc.untilDate">
<input type="time" ng-model="tsc.untilTime">
```

In my Angular Controller both model elements are objects from type Date by default.
With input type="date" the time of this Date object is always 00:00. 
With input type="time" the date part of the Date object ist allways set to today. 
So i just read the daytime (if it is set) of the TimeDate Object and set it on the DateObject.

```
if(tsc.untilTime)
{
  tsc.untilDate.setHours(tsc.untilTime.getHours());
  tsc.untilDate.setMinutes(tsc.untilTime.getMinutes());
}
```

Comment: This was really the easiest option. Not sure why the other options are higher voted

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a compact version install the momentjs library.

```
npm install moment --save
```

Add it to your file header.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Then just compose the `dateTime` object with the fluent interface.

```
let dateTime = moment(this.sdate)
    .startOf('day')
    .set('hour', this.sTime.getHours())
    .set('minute', this.sTime.getMinutes() )
    .toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const timeAndDate = moment(this.sdate + ' ' + this.sTime.getHours() + ' '  +  this.sTime.getMinutes());

console.log(timeAndDate.toDate());
```