# Get a combined Date from ui.bootstrap date and time pickers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui.bootstrap

I'm trying to combine the Datepicker and Timepicker directives to get the date from the first and the time from the second in a combined Date object. I came across some examples that are not using these directives like this one [Combining Date and Time input strings as a Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553132/combining-date-and-time-input-strings-as-a-date-object). However when I try to apply something similar to my case it's not working. Console returns "TypeError: $scope.dt.split is not a function". Above is the function I try to use which is called by $watch.

```
function tryCombineDateTime() {
    if ($scope.dt && $scope.mytime) {
        var dateParts = $scope.dt.split('-');
        var timeParts = $scope.mytime.split(':');
        if (dateParts && timeParts) {
            dateParts[1] -= 1;
            $scope.fullDate = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, dateParts.concat(timeParts))).toISOString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a plunker showing the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/tnbE3LWQTTzLhLWXLCQB?p=preview

I would prefer a solution based on my Plunker as I don't want to install other components like DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format has been changed, so exception is being thrown, Try this

```
  function tryCombineDateTime() {
    if ($scope.dt && $scope.mytime) {
      var date = $scope.dt.toString();
      var time = $scope.mytime.toString();
      var dateParts = date.split(' ');
      var timeParts = time.split(' ');
      if (dateParts && timeParts) {
        dateParts[4] = timeParts[4]
        $scope.fullDate = new Date(dateParts.join(' ')).toISOString();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your tryCombineDateTime function sould be like this:

```
  function tryCombineDateTime() {
    if ($scope.dt && $scope.mytime) {
        $scope.fullDate =new Date($scope.dt.getFullYear(), $scope.dt.getMonth(), $scope.dt.getDate(),$scope.mytime.getHours(),$scope.mytime.getMinutes()).toISOString();
    }
  }
```

this a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ttc1qQn9SUGqDjFZOnTv?p=preview) forked from your plunker

Comment: Thanks for this clean solution. However I think there is an issue. Whenever I pick a time it's not getting transformed in UTC time. The same time you pick from the form the same exact time is printed as UTC.

Comment: I changed it to that and it worked $scope.fullDate =new Date($scope.dt.getFullYear(), $scope.dt.getMonth(), $scope.dt.getDate(),$scope.mytime.getHours(),$scope.mytime.getMinutes()).toISOString();